# C# WPF - Style Triggers not working in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, styles, datatemplate

I am trying to add triggers to a WPF DataTemplate, which I will use as a cell template in my DataGrid. I need to do this programatically, so it is all in the code behind. I want the border to be highlighted when you mouse over it, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
DataTemplate dt = new DataTemplate();

// other implementation

Trigger t1 = new Trigger() { Property = IsMouseOverProperty, Value = true };
t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(BorderBrushProperty, System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black));
t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(4.0)));
dt.Triggers.Add(t1);

// add to visual tree, and other logic that works perfectly.
```

The only thing that doesn't work is this trigger. It doesn't highlight the border when I mouse over the cells. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the elements that the `Trigger` and the `Setters` are operating on.

Set the `SourceName` property of the Trigger and the `TargetName` of the Setters:

```
var dt = new DataTemplate();

var t1 = new Trigger()
{
    SourceName = "source",
    Property = IsMouseOverProperty,
    Value = true
};

t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black, "target"));
t1.Setters.Add(new Setter(BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(4.0), "target"));
dt.Triggers.Add(t1);
```

Comment: what will be the source name and target name here?